# Setting variable depending upon RAILS_ENV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This is my current controller : 'trace_controller.rb'

```
rule_oms = Rule.new("localhost","root","","oms_local")
rule_warehouse=Rule.new("localhost","root","","warehouse_local")
rule_payment=Rule.new("localhost","root","","payment_local")
```

...
....
We have 2 different modes - Staging and Production. They have Hostname, Pwd, User, Database name which are unique.

How can I change these settings from environment.rb? Can you set variables depending upon them?

Depending upon environment, I get the hostname, pwd, user, db_name for all the different databases. Unlike most Rails app, I connect to several databases irrespective of the environment.

Any ideas what I should be doing? (Using latest version of Rails).

Comment: what errors are you receiving?

Comment: I am trying to define constants now, but this is the error I get -  ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished

Answer (score 1):

in config folder --> environments --> add another file with your environment name

by default, development.rb, , test.rb and production.rb are present.
add lets say qa_1.rb for your qa_1 environment.

Set your required config in this file, you can copy it from any of the existing environment files and change them as needed.

run your rails app with RAILS_ENV=qa_1

it will take the config from qa_1.rb file

you can set probably settings_logic gem, to set envirornment wise values

gem 'settingslogic'

Then in app/models/settings.rb add

```
class Settings < Settingslogic
  source "#{Rails.root}/config/application.yml"
  namespace Rails.env
end
```

and in /config/application.yml
set you environment specific data

```
defaults: &defaults
  db: default_db
development:
  user: dev_user
test:
  user: test_user
production:
  user: prod_user
  db: prod_db
qa_1:
  user: qa_1_user
  db: qa_1_db
```

in database.yml also you can use

```
qa_1:
  db: qa_db
  user: user
```

Comment: Don't think my question was clear..Have made major modification to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve but if you place this in `environment.rb`, then I can only guess that you want some sort of global constant.  If this is what you want, I suggest you create a file inside `config/initializers` called `constants.rb` then place the following there.

```
RULE_OMS = Rule.new("oms-#{Rails.env}") 
RULE_WAREHOUSE = Rule.new("warehouse_#{Rails.env}")
RULE_PAYMENT = Rule.new("payment_#{Rails.env}")
```

then just call `RULE_OMS` anywhere in your app.

Comment: I haven't give the entire picture, this app is more like a viewing interface, which connects to several databases at once. So each mode, has different databases to connect to. I connect to the database via Sequel, and the connection is defined in model Rules.rb. Will the global constants still help?

Comment: @Jnvill - Have a look a the modified question. Do you think I should define all these constants in constants.rb? Also can we have model objects as constants?

Comment: when you mean object, do you mean AR object?  if that's what you mean, i'd suggest against it.

Comment: It's fixed...Just posted my solution above.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me -:

1) Creation of local.rb in config/environments (Simply a copy of development)

2) Defining the parameters for local in database.yml

3) Setting parameters in config/environment.rb

```
if Rails.env.local?
  OMS_HOST="localhost"
  OMS_DB="oms_local"
  OMS_USER="root"
  OMS_PWD=""

  WAREHOUSE_HOST="localhost"
  WAREHOUSE_DB="warehouse_local"
  WAREHOUSE_USER="root"
  WAREHOUSE_PWD=""

  PAYMENT_HOST="localhost"
  PAYMENT_DB="payment_local"
  PAYMENT_USER="root"
  PAYMENT_PWD=""
end

if Rails.env.development?
  OMS_HOST="amt.com"
  OMS_DB="oms_staging"
  OMS_USER="user1"
  OMS_PWD="xyz"
....
.....
```

4) In the trace_controller.rb, I used these constants to initialize my Rule model.

5) Add this in the .gitignore file, if you are using it.

6) Don't forget to restart the server.

Apologize for the way my question was framed as it was pretty unclear. Hope this answer will help somebody in the future.